# Maximum size of a ruleset – Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

what should someone do if the [maximum size of a Firestore ruleset](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure) was reached (64kb)? I don't have complex rules but rather lots of variables to check. Mostly I check for type and value. Guess they added up quickly :( What is the preferred course of action here? Should someone not be thorough and not check for variables types, for example, in order to not exceed the limit? I was trying to be as thorough as possible and then I ran into the size limitation. Is there any way to circumvent the limit or an advice on what to check for and what not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to reduce the total size, depending on what your rules actually do:

- Use functions to share redundant code across rules
- Use recursive wildcards to apply common rules to documents in nested subcollections
- Shorten the names of any wildcards
- Write code to compact rules before uploading by eliminating unnecessary leading whitespace

It's not advisable to eliminate rules entirely.  If you do need to do that for whatever reason, you will need to make a judgement call.  We can't tell you which rules are more important than others for your particular use cases.

I also suggest [filing a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) to indicate what you need from the system.